# Firewalld: Reject All Destinations

Tags: firewalld

I'm running CentOS 7. How would I go about rejecting all outgoing traffic? Most of my reading has been related to `firewalld` & `firewall-cmd`. I think I could write the rich rule, but I'm not sure which zones I would need to add it to.

I have a public zone which contains the only interface on the 'server' and I have a work zone which contains all local network sources. So, if I wanted to reject all destinations, would I have to add the rich rule to both zones? Is there a better way to approach this? Should I be looking at `iptables`?